# Whatsapp Media Messages

Tags: twilio, message, media, whatsapp, twilio-php

In the docs, it is mentioned that only during session images we can send media images. But I know some companies out there are sending media messages if no session starts. How are they doing it? Is there any workaround to send media messages without an active session?

Are there solutions from Twilio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We refer to this feature as **Media message templates**. They allow for a variety of different use cases that expand what is possible with text-only messages and require pre-approval by WhatsApp and behave similarly to standard templates.

This feature is currently in private beta. So you can wait until it'll be released (I can't give you an exact timeline here) or ask to be included by opening a ticket with our Ops team (messaging-channels-ops@twilio.com).